# CreatePolygonRgn and const POINT *

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gdi

I give you only the lines concerning my problem. I don't know why this does not compile:

```
POINT ptVertex[5];

ptVertex[0].x = 180;
ptVertex[0].y = 80;
ptVertex[1].x = 100;
ptVertex[1].y = 160;
ptVertex[2].x = 120;
ptVertex[2].y = 260;
ptVertex[3].x = 240;
ptVertex[3].y = 260;
ptVertex[4].x = 260;
ptVertex[4].y = 160;

CreatePolygonRgn( &ptVertex, 5, ALTERNATE )
```

I compile on DevC++ TDM GCC 64bits and the error is:

> cannot convert 'POINT (*)[5] {aka tagPOINT (*)[5]}' to 'const POINT* {aka const tagPOINT*}' for argument '1' to 'HRGN__* CreatePolygonRgn(const POINT*, int, int)'

If someone can find my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. And pick one of the two **different** languages C or C++!

Comment: What is the signature of the function `CreatePolygonRgn`? i.e. What is its declaration?

Comment: This is the signature : WINGDIAPI HRGN WINAPI CreatePolygonRgn( CONST POINT * pptl, int cPoint, int iMode )

Comment: Do `CreatePolygonRgn( ptVertex, 5, ALTERNATE )`. This way you are passing the address of the first element instead the address of the array (same values but different types).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreatePolygonRgn()` expects a pointer to the first `POINT` in an array, and the number of items in the array.  But you are passing it a pointer to the array itself, not its first element.  You can either:

1. index to the first element of the array before applying the `&` operator:

   ```
   CreatePolygonRgn( &ptVertex[0], 5, ALTERNATE )
   ```
2. Simply remove the `&` operator altogether, as a static array can degrade into a pointer to its first element:

   ```
   CreatePolygonRgn( ptVertex, 5, ALTERNATE )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the address of an array of five, while the function requires the address of an element and the length.